# XORing Colors and their usage?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have read that a xor b is: `(a.(not)b +  (not)a.b)` and clearly `(a xor a)=0 or False`

So the Truth Table is:

```
a|b|a xor b
-----------
0|0|   0   
0|1|   1   
1|0|   1   
1|1|   0
```

after all of above, what's the xor operation in colors. I know that the colors are hexadecimal numbers.

And What's They Usage in ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine in BkColor parameter?

Comment: `a xor b` is `0` if `a == b`, else it's `1`. That is, it's an or, where only one of the two are allowed to be true. (That's the "exclusive" part.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all your truth table is wrong:

It give 1 of a!=b, 0 otherwise.

Second the point used in graphics is (at least was in Pascal :) you can draw a shape and each pixel's color will be Original_pixel_color XOR shape_color. If you do this twice, the shape disappears because double XOR gives you the original input.

I used it e.g. when I was drawing something in simple graphic editor. When you create the object using mouse you can simply draw it using this special XOR usage without need to remember the background, because you can erase it simply by drawing it again (when for example sizing or moving the object dragged by mouse).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have got confused by double xor experssion . Please Explain more , thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Each bit of the color is individually XOR-ed.  That typically means 8 bits of red, 8 green, 8 blue, and within a color, each bit is worth half as much as the one next to it.

So for example, light gray XOR red yields kind of a sea blue:

```
R        G        B            R        G        B         R        G        B
CC       CC       CC       XOR FF       00       00      
11001100 11001100 11001100  ^  11111111 00000000 0000000 = 00110011 11001100 11001100
                                                           33       CC       CC
```